# Arduino Modbus RTU Response over serial?

Tags: arduino, modbus, rs485

I am developing a project where I have to read the holding registers data. I check everything using this http://www.freemodbus.com/ and it is working and get a proper response. While trying with the developed program I am not getting the proper response.

Software Response: 0x01 0x03 0x04 0x1a 0xa0 0x42 0x48 0xcd 0x9f
Arduino response: 0x01 0x04 0x83 0x43 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff

note that in Arduino response there is no 0x03 after 0x01 I don't know why it is happening can anyone please help me with this.

please find attached Arduino code below.

```
static union
  {
    unsigned long a;
    byte b[4];
    float f;

  }vr;


void readregister(unsigned int address)
{
  byte rxbuf[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
  byte data[] = {0x01,0x03,0x00,0xab,0x00,0x02,0xb5,0xeb};
  Serial3.flush();
  for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
  {
    Serial3.write(data[i]);
  }
  delay(250);
  while(Serial3.available()>0)
  {
    for(int v=0; v<=10;v++)
    {
      rxbuf[v]=Serial3.read();
      Serial.println(rxbuf[v],HEX);
    }
  }
  Serial3.flush();
  vr.b[3]=rxbuf[3];
  vr.b[2]=rxbuf[2];
  vr.b[1]=rxbuf[5];
  vr.b[0]=rxbuf[4];


}
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial3.begin(9600,SERIAL_8E1);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
   readregister(99);
  Serial.print("\n");

  delay(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you're getting an Error code 4 back from the device. See http://www.simplymodbus.ca/exceptions.htm

On this line, where you prep your request:

> byte data[] = {0x01,0x03,0x00,0xab,0x00,0x02,0xb5,0xeb};

You're saying, device 1, function 3, 0x00 is space, then register address 0xAB. Not sure about the extra zero then, then length 2, and then CRC. So I vote that either the CRC is wrong, or the extra zero is wrong.

Also, note that modbus fails on ocassion for no reason, even when you do everything right, so retry after a few seconds and see what happens

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I get by doing troubleshooting is that while reading the byte by byte data from UART printing it after reading it takes a time during which sent data is being missed by UART and is not able to store it. So by removing the serial.println line my problem is solved. Your answer is correct but not in this case here what ever data we get is from response only but it is not complete. So by removing the line UART and code which stored the incoming data have enough time so that it is ready for next coming data.